# Android google maps drawing roads performanse issue with 10.000+ overlay

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, dictionary

I am working on a project which is aboot drawing roads and displaying some informations about the roads. The issue is that  I am using so many geopoints( 5.000-10.000 +) and drawing line points to points and showing the roads with different colors, **so the map is too slow.** I did some configurations about my application but still too slow. 
Do you have any idea about solving my problem and being the performance  better?

Here is the my code.

```
for (int t = 0; t < roads.size(); t++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < roads.get(t).size() - 1; i++) {
                                //bounds up-bottom-right-left to draw roads
                if (boundBox[0] >= roads.get(t).get(i)
                        .getLatitudeE6()
                        && boundBox[1] >= roads.get(t).get(i)
                                .getLongitudeE6()
                        && boundBox[2] <= roads.get(t).get(i)
                                .getLatitudeE6()
                        && boundBox[3] <= roads.get(t).get(i)
                                .getLongitudeE6()) {


                    MyOverlay mOverlay = new MyOverlay();
                    mOverlay.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                    mOverlay.setWidth(4);
                    mOverlay.setPair(roads.get(t).get(i),
                            roads.get(t).get(i + 1));
                    mapOverlays.add(mOverlay);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
 class MyOverlay extends Overlay {

            GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
            GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
            int colr=0,width=0;



            public MyOverlay() {

            }

            public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
                super.draw(canvas, mapv, false);

                Paint mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setDither(true);
                mPaint.setColor(colr);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);

                Point p1 = new Point();
                Point p2 = new Point();

                Path path = new Path();

                Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
                projection.toPixels(gp1, p1);
                projection.toPixels(gp2, p2);

                path.moveTo((float) p2.x, (float) p2.y);
                path.lineTo((float) p1.x, (float) p1.y);


                // canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, point.x, point.y, null);

                canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
                //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);

            }

            public void setPair(GeoPoint gpone, GeoPoint gptwo) {

                gp1 = gpone;
                gp2 = gptwo;

            }

            public void setColor(int clr)
            {
                colr=clr;
            }

            public void setWidth(int w)
            {
                width=w;
            }


        }
```

Is there anyone to solve my issue ?

Comment: some coding of how you are implementing these 5000-10000+ will be useful, because maybe you are not implementing it in efficient way

Comment: I have this same doubt, somebody can help us ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do to improve efficiency.

Your first block of code could be made slightly more efficient:

```
for (int t = 0, size = roads.size(); t < size; t++) { //Avoid calling '.size()' over and over
    for (int i = 0; i < roads.get(t).size() - 1; i++) {//Avoid calling '.size()' over and over
        final GeoPoint road = roads.get(t).get(i); //Reduce the number of get() calls.
        if (boundBox[0] >= road.getLatitudeE6()
            && boundBox[1] >= road.getLongitudeE6()
            && boundBox[2] <= road.getLatitudeE6()
            && boundBox[3] <= road.getLongitudeE6()) {
                MyOverlay mOverlay = new MyOverlay();
                mOverlay.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                mOverlay.setWidth(4);
                mOverlay.setPair(road, roads.get(t).get(i + 1));
                mapOverlays.add(mOverlay);
        }
    }
}
```

But most importantly, the biggest performance drain I can see in your code is that you are allocating a new rendering objects (Paint, Path, Point) every time draw() is called. This can be refactored so you reuse the same Paint instance:

```
class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
    GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
    GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();
    Path path = new Path();
    int colr=0,width=0;

    public MyOverlay() {
          Paint mPaint = new Paint();
          mPaint.setDither(true);
          mPaint.setColor(colr);
          mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
          mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
          mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
          mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }

      public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
          super.draw(canvas, mapv, false);

          path.reset();

          Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
          projection.toPixels(gp1, p1);
          projection.toPixels(gp2, p2);

          path.moveTo((float) p2.x, (float) p2.y);
          path.lineTo((float) p1.x, (float) p1.y);
          canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
      }
  }
```

For more info see the 'Do's and Dont's section of the article here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html.

The relevant point from the article is: *"Don't create render objects in draw methods: a common mistake is to create a new Paint, or a new Path, every time a rendering method is invoked. This is not only wasteful, forcing the system to run the GC more often, it also bypasses caches and optimizations in the hardware pipeline."*

Comment: Thanks bro. Great job. I have reduced size() and get() methods. I do not use them now. It's faster than the old one. Now, I am trying your suggestion. thx again.