# How to draw a path on google maps by zip code

Tags: google-maps

I want to show a path map and distance between to points by zip code or city name l ike we enter to and from place and map will generate between them , total distance between them will be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three steps 
1) generate map by post city or zip code 
create map1.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example:Post City or Zip</title>
  </head>
<body >
<form action="map2.php" method="post" >
Enter 1st zip code / city <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"><br/>
Enter 2nd zip code / city <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Create map2.php and generate map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = '<?php echo $_POST['input1']; ?>';
    var end = '<?php echo $_POST['input2']; ?>';


    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize(),calcRoute()">
  <?php
  // calculate laglong by address and zip code
  function getLatLong($address){
    if (!is_string($address))die("All Addresses must be passed as a string");
    $_url = sprintf('http://maps.google.com/maps?output=js&q=%s',rawurlencode($address));
    $_result = false;
    if($_result = file_get_contents($_url)) {
        if(strpos($_result,'errortips') > 1 || strpos($_result,'Did you mean:') !== false) return false;
        preg_match('!center:\s*{lat:\s*(-?\d+\.\d+),lng:\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)}!U', $_result, $_match);
        $_coords['lat'] = $_match[1];
        $_coords['long'] = $_match[2];
    }
    return $_coords;
}
  $to = getLatLong($_POST['input1']);echo "<br/>";print_r($to);
  $from = getLatLong($_POST['input2']);echo "<br/>";print_r($from);
echo distance($to['lat'], $to['long'], $from['lat'], $from['long'], "m") . " miles";

//  // calculate distance by lat long
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}
?>


<div id="map_canvas" style="top:30px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

that generate map and getLatLong() function find laglong and distance function find distance between city or zip code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to find geolocation of your zipcode which you can find it easily using gmaps api. Then use "distanceTo" method to find distance between to points (your geopoint and zip code generated geopoint) . distanceTo method gives you distance in meters.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729951/android-google-maps-drawing-roads-performanse-issue-with-10-000-overlay)